# Why is there no article before "key" in "key amongst them being ..."?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, zero-article, appositives, gerund-phrases, fused-head-constructions

Why is there no article before *key* in the sentence?

> There are however pressing challenges for both systems, key amongst them being the need for better IT skills on the part of students and teachers.

Source: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&sou...FjAKegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw1vanGVOuCeK6Iqllk7jLpz

Comment: Would using some other adjective here, like perhaps *first*, bother you as well?

Comment: ... ... But wouldn't 'the chief' also work?

Answer (score 4):

Key here is an adjective not a noun, meaning important or crucial in achieving something.

Example: "When it comes to learning a new language, practice is key"

Comment: Can it be a mass noun? Why can an adjective function as the logical subject of the present participle 'being'? Adjectives functioning as logical subjects doesn't seem to work in 'I have a lot of friends, smart being Amy. '
But i can see 'the smartest' working. Is it because the superlative and 'key' are definite because there's only one that's the best/smartest/whatever and there's only one that's the key. Now you see here I want to use a definite article before key

Comment: It's an adjective. The meaning here is the adjectival meaning, ["extremely or crucially important,"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/key) and not the noun meaning, ["something that gives an explanation or identification or provides a solution."](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/key) And while you can't use the adjective *smart* that way, you could use the adjectives *[paramount](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paramount)* or *[foremost](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foremost)* (and probably many others).

Comment: If it really bothers you imagine that 'key' is the only part of the phrase "the key challenge" which remains after 'the' and 'challenge' have been suppressed to avoid repetition. I'm not sure that this is what is happening but, in the absence of a more authoritative answer it does make sense of the missing subject. You need to understand that this formation is widely used and accepted in formal pieces of writing anyway.

Comment: @BoldBen In CGEL it's what H&P call a ‘fused-modifier head’. Only the modifier of the original noun remains, and that becomes the head of the whittled-down NP. The means that *key amongst them* (which is an **NP PREP NP** structurally, and *key* its head)  is the subject of the nonfinite-verb clause whose verb is *being*.The entire subordinate clause is used appositively.

Comment: @tchrist I like that, I was hoping that someone wold have a better explanation than mine but I don't think that I was that far away really. Your explanation of the 'fused modifier head' where 'only the modifier of the original noun remains' is similar in practical effect to the suppression of the rest of the noun phrase to me.

Comment: @tchrist Could you tell me what 'NP' stands for?

Comment: @Jenny An NP is a noun phrase, which is anything that can serve in the grammatical role of subject, object, etc. It doesn't have to have a noun as its head, although most do so. For example, *To resist is essential* has no nouns in it, and the NP which is the subject is actually an infinitive verb, not a noun at all.